# Loop through JSON array for comparisons in python?

Tags: python, json

is there a way to loop through two sets of JSON arrays and identify the additional array items from File 2 compared to File 1? Example below:

File 1:

```
{
    "Cars": [{
            "type": "Ford"
        },
        {
            "type": "BMW"
        }
    ]
}
```

File: 2

```
{
    "Cars": [{
            "type": "Ford"
        },
        {
            "type": "BMW"
        },
        {
            "type": "Vauxhall"
        },      
        {
            "type": "Fiat"
        }
    ]
}
```

Desired outcome:

The additons are:

```
{
        "Cars": [{
                "type": "Vauxhall"
            },      
            {
                "type": "Fiat"
            }
        ]
    }
```

I am struggling to get into the array in Python. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the most optimal or the finest method, but it should work

Assuming you've arrays as `dict` in python

```
a = []
b = []
for val in array1["Cars"]:
    a.append(val["type"])
for val in array2["Cars"]:
    b.append(val["type"])
diff = ( set(a) | set(b) ) - ( set(a) & set(b) )
```

You can iterate over `diff` and create json/dict in required format.

Answer (score 1):

If your data is this simple use `in`:

```
for c in y['Cars']:
  if c not in x['Cars']:
    print(c)
```

Or as a list comprehension:

```
diff_dict = {'Cars': [c for c in y['Cars'] if c not in x['Cars']]}
```

Output:

```
{'Cars': [{'type': 'Vauxhall'}, {'type': 'Fiat'}]}
```

You mentioned you were having a hard time getting the files into python.  I used `json.load()`

Comment: What if x array has the extra elements ? This will work only if he knows which one has extra elements.